# Angular2 Pipes with parameter

Tags: angular, input, pipe

i'm working with pipes and i'm thinking to use a pipe with a string parameter as a @input component value. Something like this:

```
  <donut-chart [labels]="portfolio.currentStrategy.assetClasses | strategyFormat:'labels'" [values]="portfolio.currentStrategy.assetClasses | strategyFormat:'percentages'"></donut-chart>
```

Can i do that?

This is myPipe

```
@Pipe({name: 'strategyFormat'})
export class StrategyFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(assetClasses: AssetClass[], type: string): any [] {
    let array: any [] = [];
    for (let i of assetClasses)
      if (type == 'labels')  array.push(i.name);
      else array.push(i.percentage);
    return array;
  }
}
```

I have this error:

```
  zone.js:516 Unhandled Promise rejection: Quotes are not supported for evaluation! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: 
ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation! at _AstToIrVisitor.visitQuote (http://localhost:…, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!↵  …2 [<root>]↵    at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]", __zone_symbol__message: "Quotes are not supported for evaluation!"}
 Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!
    at _AstToIrVisitor.visitQuote (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:18169:15) [<root>]
    at Quote.visit (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:38853:24) [<root>]
    at ASTWithSource.visit (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:39431:25) [<root>]
    at convertPropertyBinding (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:17698:50) [<root>]
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:81390:165 [<root>]
    at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
    at bindDirectiveInputs (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:81386:25) [<root>]
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:81565:113 [<root>]
    at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
    at ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:81563:24) [<root>]
    at ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:7932:24) [<root>]
    at visit (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:8213:37) [<root>]
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:8215:42 [<root>]
    at Array.forEach (native) [<root>]
```

I also tried without the single quotes. But that gives me the same error.

Comment: I think that error comes from `myPipe` not from the markup you posted in your question. Please post the `transform(...)` code. Perhaps also the full stack trace instead of just the error message.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: Do you get an error for `<div>{{portfolio.currentStrategy.assetClasses | strategyFormat:'labels' | json }}</div>` ?

Comment: String interpolation is not my case because i'm using the pipe to filter the data passed to component input element.

Comment: It still would show if the error comes from your pipe, your view bindings or from the donut-chart component.

Comment: Yes, in this way it works. The JSON is displayed.

Comment: Then I'm sure the problem is in `<donut-chart>`